# One table update accoriding to another table MySQL update error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables name activties and post_media now I want to update the media background color in activities table according to post media table record but when I run query it give me error.

**Query**

```
UPDATE A
SET A.bg_color = M.bg_color
FROM activities A
INNER JOIN post_media M ON A.relation_id = M.user_post_id AND A.media=M.file
WHERE A.relation_id>0
```

**Error**

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use**
>   **near 'FROM activities A INNER JOIN post_media M ON A.relation_id =
>   M.user_post_' at line 3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update query with use of join is different than SELECT query. Here you need to add tables before SET clause and all conditions in WHERE clause like SELECT.

e.g/
    UPDATE t1, t2 
    SET t1.field = t2.field 
    WHERE condition 1
    AND condition 2

So your query will be like as below:

```
UPDATE activities A, post_media M
SET A.bg_color = M.bg_color
WHERE A.relation_id = M.user_post_id 
AND A.media=M.file
AND A.relation_id>0
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 4):

`UPDATE` syntax is different from `SELECT`. There is no `FROM` clause usage in `UPDATE` statement.

General flow is: `UPDATE <table name> [JOIN <other tables>] SET ...`

```
UPDATE activities A
INNER JOIN post_media M ON A.relation_id = M.user_post_id AND A.media=M.file
SET A.bg_color = M.bg_color
WHERE A.relation_id>0
```

Check documentation here for full syntax and further understanding: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html